# In "Mel spectrogram" or "Mel filterbanks", what does Mel mean and why is it often capitalized?

Tags: audio, audio-processing, speech-processing, filter-bank

In "Mel spectrogram" or "Mel filterbanks", what does Mel mean and why is it capitalized ? It doesn't seem to be the name of a person.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_scale): The mel scale (**after the word** ***melody***) is a perceptual scale of pitches judged by listeners to be equal in distance from one another. The reference point between this scale and normal frequency measurement is defined by assigning a perceptual pitch of 1000 mels to a 1000 Hz tone, 40 dB above the listener's threshold. Above about 500 Hz, increasingly large intervals are judged by listeners to produce equal pitch increments.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can be answered by googling.

Comment: @MattL. The question has two parts, and it seems that the second part remains unanswered for now.

Comment: cc @ZaellixA as well, thanks for the reference to Wikipedia.